# Using an abstract class create different classes with user input

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a program where The user picks 1,2,3 to pick a rectangle, triangle, or square; or zero to exit. Then the user gives the width and height of the shape and then It outputs the shape name, width and height as well as calculates the area.

in my public Rectangle(int width, int height) and my public Square(int height) and public Triangle(int width, int height) class they all give the same error..."There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter "width" of GeometricFigure.GeometricFigure(int, int) what exactly does that mean and how to fix it?

I'm just trying to get my logic right any help is appreciated!

using System;

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    Rectangle r;
    Square s;
    Triangle t;
    int number;
    string value = null;

    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Choose a shape from the following options ");
        Console.WriteLine("[1] Rectangle");
        Console.WriteLine("[2] Square");
        Console.WriteLine("[3] Triangle");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the option number (or zero to terminate this program): ");
        number = Int32.Parse(value);
        Console.Write(number);
    }
    while (number != 0);

        if (number == 0)
        {
           Console.WriteLine();
           Console.WriteLine("Please press <enter> to terminate this program");
           Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else if (number == 1)
        {
        Console.Write("Please press enter the width and then hit enter: ");
        int width = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Please press enter the height and then hit enter: ");
        int height = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        r = new Rectangle(width, height);
    }
        else if (number == 2)
        {

        Console.Write("Please press enter the height and then hit enter: ");
        int height = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        s = new Square(height);
    }
        else if (number == 3)
        {
        Console.Write("Please press enter the width and then hit enter: ");
        int width = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Please press enter the height and then hit enter: ");
        int height = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        t = new Triangle(width, height);
    }

}
}
    public abstract class GeometricFigure
{
         private readonly int width;
         private readonly int height;
         private readonly double area; 


        public GeometricFigure(int width, int height)
        {

        }

        public abstract double computeArea
        {
            get;
        }



         public int Width
        {
             get { return width; }

        }

         public int Height
        {
             get { return height; }

        }

     }   


     public class Rectangle : GeometricFigure
  {
         private int width;
         private int height;

        public Rectangle(int width, int height)
        {

        }

        public override double computeArea
        {
        get { return width * height; }
        }

    }




      public class Square : Rectangle
{
        private int side;


        public Square(int height)
        {

            side = height;
        }

        public override double computeArea 
        {
         get
        {
        // Given the side, return the area of a square:
        return side * side;
    }

}
}

    public class Triangle : GeometricFigure
    {

        public Triangle(int width, int height)
        {

        }
        public override double computeArea
        {


          get { return (Width * Height) / 2; }


        }
    }
```

Comment: you can *declare* an object without *instantiating* it.  Logically, you can't create a rectangle without a height and width; and syntactically, you need those parameters for your constructor.  Don't instantiate your object until you know how to.  But this code is too much of a mess for a good answer.

Comment: Yeah I'm lost when It comes to doing anything with more than one class I've been on this problem for 4 days now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you start by commenting out Square and Triangle so that you can focus on your Rectangle (or whichever shape you prefer).

Your GeometricShape needs an abstract property called "area" see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd3z1377.aspx

Your `Rectangle` constructor should not call the base constructor with type declarations and the parameter names must match. To show you what I mean:

```
base(int number, int _width, int _height, double area)
```

should be

```
base(number, width, height, area)
```

You will need to pass some values to your constructors like this:

```
int number = 1;  // The shape you want
int width = 10;
int height = 20;
double area = width * height;

r = new Rectangle(number, width, height, area)
```

You should also declare your rectangle without instantiating as @jonesopolis suggested.

e.g.

```
Rectangle r;
```

Hope that helps.

Edit:

Here is the example for reading some numbers from the console and passing them to the Rectangle constructor:

```
else if (number == 1)
{
    Console.Write("Please press enter the width and then hit enter: ");
    int width = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Please press enter the height and then hit enter: ");
    int height = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    double area = width * height;

    r = new Rectangle(number, width, height, area);
}
```

Comment: I don't know what values will be passed through, the user will give those values after they pick 1,2,3 or 0 to exit.

Comment: In that case you need some variables to store whatever you read from the console. You have an example of this where you are reading the number variable in the do while loop. You can do it using Conslole.ReadLine(); Check out the examples here.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I see...making it equal to a name like "number" instead of having it equal to already set int's or doubles...is that right?

Comment: Hmm, not sure. But I have updated my answer with an (rough) example of a way to do it. Normally you would need error checking but this will work provided you always enter numbers when prompted.

Comment: So I shouldn't put my constructors in my main method? And I guess I don't need number in my argument if 2 already refers to square in another class.  In my else if statements my Rectangle() says it is a non invocable member "rectangle" cannot be used like a method. But isn't rectangle a method and a class?

Comment: Agreed, you _may_ not need "number" as an argument. Rectangle's constructor must be used with the new keyword to create a new object of that type. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms173115.aspx

Comment: Yeah I updated my code..I got rid of the base( number, width, height, area) next to each of my rectangle, square, triangle classes. Will that do anything...I have the same errors in all 3 my classes..I edited that to in the main description.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109000/discussion-between-mcgee-and-mvanderk10).

Answer (score 1):

First off, where are you getting user input? You declare value but you never assign anything to it but null.

To answer your question, you are declaring the Rectangle constructor with four arguments (number, height width and area), but when you call the constructor, you give it none. I do not see why number and area need to be arguments to its constructor, it doesn't care about anything other than its height, width and area, so giving it number makes no sense, and giving it area doesn't make sense because it should calculate that, not be told it.

To fix your problem, I would change the arguments of the constructor to just `int width, int height` and then pass in a width and height into the constructor (`Rectangle(someValue,someOtherValue);`).

You will need to apply this fix to square and triangle as well.

Third, a small syntax error, you do not need to restate the type when passing arguments into the base constructor. Just stating the variable names or values you want to pass in will do.

Sorry if that was a bit of an info dump, but I hope it helps.

Comment: I put the number because how is 2 supposed to know to go to square? I haven;'t put the input for width and height i'm assuming its a good idea to put it in the individual classes?

Comment: The code knows to go from 2 to square with: `else if (number == 2) { Square(); }`. As for your second concern, C# still needs to see some argument in the constructor. I would suggest just `Square(2,2);` and then replace the 2's with the actual values once you implement them.

Comment: what do those 2's represent? Just placeholders?

Comment: Actually type the number 2. While they are placeholders for debugging purposes, you need to give the code some value, so just pick a random integer to type their directly.

Comment: yeah I agree with the int width and int height as my arguements, I have to create a computeArea() method anyway...but If we don't know what values will be picked what would go in my else if Square(); ? Square(int width, int height);?

Comment: `Square(2,2);` That is a call so you have to give it real values. The `int width` syntax is for variable declarations and method definitions only.